# How can I force "list-buffers" to use the other window

Tags: buffers

When I type C-x C-b (i.e. the command list-buffers), how can I force it to list buffers in the other window? i.e. I typically have my screen split into 2 buffers. I am editing one buffer. I want a command which *always* lists buffers in the other window.

p.s. list-buffers used to always do this. But somewhere between emacs 24.3 and 24.5 it changed, so now it sometimes puts the buffer list in the current window.

Comment: Here is a link to a related thread entitled **Make *Buffer List* always appear in horizontal split**:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542914/make-buffer-list-always-appear-in-horizontal-split  Here is a link to a related thread entitled **How to make *Buffer List* appear below the other windows?**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591177/how-to-make-buffer-list-appear-below-the-other-windows A dedicated window can affect how the display-buffer family of functions operate -- here is a link to the manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered the command buffer-menu-other-window, which seems to do what I want. It'll take a few hours of use before I'm sure.

Comment: 1 day later and I'm happy with that solution. I set it to a key shortcut (F5 in my case) so I don't need to type the command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, buffer-menu-other-window is the solution, rebind C-x C-b in your `.emacs` file and you can permanently restore the default behavior of earlier emacs releases.

```
(global-set-key "\C-x\C-b" 'buffer-menu-other-window)
```